# Add rows with dates till January next year

Tags: r

i do have quite complicated case for me to solve. Let me explain you on the base of an example..So we start with the table below:

```
 Datum Urlaub_geplannt
1 2018-10            1410
2 2018-11             940
3 2018-12             470


structure(list(Datum = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-10", "2018-11", 
"2018-12"), class = "factor"), Urlaub_geplannt = c(1410, 940, 
470)), .Names = c("Datum", "Urlaub_geplannt"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to get the new rows added to this table till January next year (Datum column) and all the other columns should be filled with 0. The final table should look in this case like that:

```
 Datum Urlaub_geplannt
1 2018-10            1410
2 2018-11             940
3 2018-12             470
4 2019-01             0
```

However it is very important to make it somehow automatically the "end year", as my data changes (it is actually in `Shiny`).

What i mean by that if i would have new data with rows from 2019, i would like automatically get the "end date" as January 2020. Thanks for help!

Comment: you need one row for each month?

Comment: yes i do need one row for each month until January next year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach

```
get_date_till_Jan <- function(df) {
  #Convert the character dates to actual Date objects
  max_Date <- max(as.Date(paste0(df$Datum, "-01")))

  #Get the date for next year January
  next_Jan <- as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(format(max_Date, "%Y")) + 1, "-01-01"))

  #Create a monthly sequence from the max date to next Jan date
  new_date <- format(seq(max_Date, next_Jan, by = "month")[-1], "%Y-%m")

  #Create a new dataframe with all values as 0 and change only the Datum 
  #column with new_date and rbind it to original dataframe
  rbind(df, transform(data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = length(new_date), 
      ncol = ncol(df), dimnames = list(NULL, names(df)))), 
      Datum = new_date))
}

df <- get_date_till_Jan(df)
df

#    Datum Urlaub_geplannt
#1 2018-10            1410
#2 2018-11             940
#3 2018-12             470
#4 2019-01               0
```

This would work for any number of columns

```
df['another_col'] = 1:4
get_date_till_Jan(df)


#     Datum Urlaub_geplannt another_col
#1  2018-10            1410           1
#2  2018-11             940           2
#3  2018-12             470           3
#4  2019-01               0           4
#5  2019-02               0           0
#6  2019-03               0           0
#7  2019-04               0           0
#8  2019-05               0           0
#9  2019-06               0           0
#10 2019-07               0           0
#11 2019-08               0           0
#12 2019-09               0           0
#13 2019-10               0           0
#14 2019-11               0           0
#15 2019-12               0           0
#16 2020-01               0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- structure(list(Datum = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-10", "2018-11", 
                                                       "2018-12"), class = "factor"), Urlaub_geplannt = c(1410, 940, 
                                                                                                          470)), .Names = c("Datum", "Urlaub_geplannt"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                       -3L), class = "data.frame")




Datum <- format(seq.Date(as.Date(paste0(df$Datum[nrow(df)],"-01")),
                         as.Date(paste0(substring(seq.Date(as.Date(paste0(as.character(df$Datum[1]),"-01")), 
                                                           length = 2,
                                                           by = 'year')[2],1,4),"-01-01")),
                         by = "month"

),"%Y-%m")


new_df <- data.frame(Datum  = Datum, Urlaub_geplannt = rep(0,length(Datum)))


total_df <- rbind(df,new_df)

total_df
#>     Datum Urlaub_geplannt
#> 1 2018-10            1410
#> 2 2018-11             940
#> 3 2018-12             470
#> 4 2018-12               0
#> 5 2019-01               0
```

Comment: thanks for answer! However i would like to automatically check "max"/ "end"  year on base of the table

Comment: so you wnt to automatically detect `2020-01` based on 2018?

Comment: I would like to check first from what kind of date(year) is the data in the table and then automatically create new rows untill January NEXT YEAR. So if my data is from 2018 in the table, then i would need rows untill January 2019, etc. Rows with date sequence should be added to table which is existing and all the other columns shoul dbe filled with 0!

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `dplyr` and a `full_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # for ymd() function


d <- d %>% 
  mutate(Datum = paste0(Datum,"-01"),
         Datum = ymd(Datum)) # correct Date format

min_year <- year(min(d$Datum))
min_date <- min(d$Datum)

# create a data.frame of possible dates
fill_dates <- data.frame(Datum = seq.Date(
  min_date, # min date avaiable
  as.Date(paste0(min_year+1,"-01-01")), # until first Jan next year
  by = "month"))
```

Now we can join the two `data.frames`:

```
d %>% 
  full_join(fill_dates, by="Datum") %>% # full_join of the two tables
  # the full_join will add all new row not present in d originally, with NA
  mutate(Urlaub_geplannt = ifelse(is.na(Urlaub_geplannt), 0, Urlaub_geplannt))

#       Datum Urlaub_geplannt
# 1 2018-10-01            1410
# 2 2018-11-01             940
# 3 2018-12-01             470
# 4 2019-01-01               0
```

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(Datum = structure(c("2018-10", "2018-11", 
                                                      "2018-12"), class = "character"), Urlaub_geplannt = c(1410, 940, 
                                                                                                         470)), .Names = c("Datum", "Urlaub_geplannt"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                      -3L), class = "data.frame")
```